# Div Scroll on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

I'm browsing a site (http://dreamsreality.co.uk/mobi/) via iPhone and other devices, however, I'm unable to scroll through the content. If you press the link "Insight" on the top-left, it'll redirect you to another page. Via a computer, you're able to scroll through the content fine. Via device such as iPhone, you're unable too. I think it's having problems scrolling through the div. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The site is just not adjusted for mobile devices.
It's barley usable using a desktop as well.